# RabbitMQ and queue data

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an application with RabbitMQ where I get the number of messages in a Rabbit queue using the HTTP API (/api/queues/vhost/name). 
However, it appears that this information is refreshed from time to time (by default every 5 seconds). I thought the information was always up to date, and it was the administration page that was updated in a given interval.

Is there any way to get the number of messages in a queue with real-time information?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The management database is updated each 5 seconds by default.

use the command line `rabbitmqctl list_queues` for real-time values.

Try to use:

`channel.messageCount(you_queue)`

see if it works for you

> `/**
>        * Returns the number of messages in a queue ready to be delivered
>        * to consumers. This method assumes the queue exists. If it doesn't,
>        * an exception will be closed with an exception.
>        * @param queue the name of the queue
>        * @return the number of messages in ready state
>        * @throws IOException Problem transmitting method.
>        */
>       long messageCount(String queue) throws IOException;`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do it from a java application, not by console (and by console it seems to be a slow query).

Comment: The messageCount method doesn't work for me, it always returns 0 messages. For more information, I am using the Spring-amqp framework.