# Spring AMQP and messages in queue

Tags: spring-amqp

In a Spring AMQP project, I would like to get the number of messages in a certain queue (to make decisions based on that number of messages) in RabbitMQ in real time (I can't use the management plugin). 
The basic configuration is this:

```
@Bean(name="managementServerHandler")
    public ManagementServerHandler managementServerHandler(){
        return new ManagementServerHandler();
    }
    @Bean 
    public MessageListenerAdapter broadcastManagementServerHandler() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(managementServerHandler(), "handleMessage");
    }
    @Bean(name="broadcastManagementMessageListenerContainer") 
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer broadcastManagementMessageListenerContainer() 
    {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(_connectionFactory());
        container.setQueueNames( REQUEST_MANAGEMENT_QUEUE );
        container.setMessageListener(broadcastManagementServerHandler());
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setAutoDeclare(true);
        container.setAutoStartup(true);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        container.setRabbitAdmin((RabbitAdmin)_amqpAdmin());
        container.setPrefetchCount(50);

        container.setDeclarationRetries(3);
        container.setMissingQueuesFatal(true);
        container.setFailedDeclarationRetryInterval(1000);
        container.setRecoveryInterval(400);

        return container;
    }
```

Where the "ManagementServerHandler" is just:

```
 public class ManagementServerHandler implements ServletContextAware, MessageListener
    {
     @Override
        public void onMessage(Message msg) 
        {....}
}
```

I need the number of queued messages in the onMessage method, but I can't find the way to do it.
I asked this question, but I don't know how to get the AMQP channel:

[RabbitMQ and queue data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980158/rabbitmq-and-queue-data)

Thanks!

Comment: For more information, I need the number of messages from another queue, not from the queue in which the container is listening. I have tried it with "channel. messageCount (your_queue)" but it always returns me zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queue)`

```
/**
 * Returns 3 properties {@link #QUEUE_NAME}, {@link #QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT},
 * {@link #QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT}, or null if the queue doesn't exist.
 */
@Override
public Properties getQueueProperties(final String queueName) {
```

Comment: Thank you, Gary. I've already tried, but it always returns me number of messages 0. The number of consumers and the name of the queue does return it well, but not the number of messages: {"QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT": 1,"QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT": 0,"QUEUE_NAME":"myRequestQueueue.8656"}

Comment: Perhaps your consumer has a large prefetch? (`basicQos`). The count (and `channel.messageCount()`) only includes `ready` messages. If they have already been sent to the consumer, they are not counted; in other words, the count doesn't include `unacked` messages.

Comment: Thank you Gary, that's actually it. I had a "Prefetch count" worth 5. I guess this doesn't fit then. Is there no way to get the total number of messages (ready and unacked)?

Comment: Not using the AMQP protocol; only REST via the admin plugin.

Comment: Thanks Gary, REST is the first option I used, but the information in that plugin is updated every five seconds, so I'll have to think of an alternative. Thank you again!